# readr's read_csv not rendering dataframe when used on url

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, jsonlite, readr

read_csv(url) is not giving me the dataframe available on the link in the following code.

```
library(tidyverse)

url = 'https://data.gov.il/dataset/f54e79b2-3e6b-4b65-a857-f93e47997d9c/resource/e4bf0ab8-ec88-4f9b-8669-f2cc78273edd/download/corona_hospitalization_ver_00185.csv'

hosp_data <- read_csv(url)
```

What am I missing here and how can I get the dataframe as dataframe?

Comment: It worked for me, but the result is not a properly formatted data.frame.

Comment: That's exactly is my problem. However, if you directly go on to that link you see a properly formatted dataframe.

Comment: If I were you, I would download the csv, then click on the file on RStudio to open the interactive screen to figure out all parameters you have to pass to the function, e.g., locale, encoding etc

Comment: I see a lot of question marks in place of variables names that are in Hebrew. So I tried col_names = F and skip =1 to try and fix that, but no luck.